# SQL Server database backup to Windows Azure Recovery Service

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-backup, sql-server-2012

I have some VMs on Windows Azure and IIS and SQL Server 2012 is installed on them.
I also created a Backup Vault on Windows Azure and installed the Windows Azure Backup Agent on the VMs.

It works well to backup the websites but not the databases.

> The modified dates change when SQL Server closes the files (SQL Server shut down or the database is detached), or when the file is grown (either automatically or manually).  All other times, SQL Server essentially bypasses the file system when performing the writes, and so the modified dates aren't updated.
>
> Source http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b7db6744-cd7b-42b5-a84e-5e511a5e8e59/mdf-ldf-files-last-modified-date-not-increasing-as-expected?forum=sqldisasterrecovery

Is there a way to backup the databases in the Backup Vault?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of backing up Data and Transaction Log files you can set up SQL Server backup to the specific folder(s) and backup those backup files into the Backup Vault.

Also, there are a number of other options how you can backup your SQL data to Azure:

- BACKUP [db] TO URL [statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn435916.aspx)
- Maintenance plans
- SQL Server [Backup to Azure Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40740)